# Revert single file in pushed commit while contributing

Tags: git

I recently contributed in react  native documentation and I forked the repo and then did 2 commits and I pushed it to my forked repo and then i merge it with their original repo.
But i did one  mistake i also pushed the yarn.lock file. Now They ask me to revert it.

"please revert the yarn.lock changes pushed in this PR"

"Like in other PR, please revert the yarn.lock changes and revert the link changes (which are already present in other PR), so the Readme.md will be the only changed file in this PR."

```
commit 0aaf169014833b32e835f50f11905afa0074fc71 (HEAD -> edit-branch-name, origin/edit-branch-name)
Author: bilal yaqoob <bilalyaqoob111996@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 27 08:13:10 2021 +0500

    edit branch name in readme

commit 681e334a04b4e0016203b191080f0e86af0f514f (origin/remove-empty-link, remove-empty-link)
Author: bilal yaqoob <bilalyaqoob111996@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 27 08:05:02 2021 +0500

    removed the empty link
```

How can i do this. As i am not very expert in git.

Answer (score 1):

This is not difficult, but they are actually asking you to do *two* things, revert the change in `yarn.lock` and revert the removal of the empty link. Those are — or might be — two completely different sorts of action.

The empty link deletion is the result of a commit. Commits can be reverted:

```
git revert 681e334
```

So much for that; you've just made a new commit that undoes your first commit. Now look at `yarn.lock`. Is it back the way you found it? If not, you're going to have to find an earlier commit that contains the old state of `yarn.lock`, restore that, and make yet another commit:

```
git restore -s <goodCommit> -- yarn.lock
git add yarn.lock
git commit -m 'bring back old yarn.lock'
```

Now just push to append your new commit(s) to the existing pull request.

Comment: "git checkout 87c20b0  -- react-native-website/yarn.lock" I used this command and commit and pushed but not seeing anything happened.

Comment: I think i successfully reverted it "@bilalyaqoob reverting yarn lock" I am seeing this in pull requests

Comment: My answer stands (though of course I don't know the actual path to the `yarn.lock` file; that's up to you). I really can't take any responsibility for commands that are totally different from what I suggested doing. You want to say `checkout`, go right ahead, it will probably work fine, but it isn't what my answer said to do.

Comment: Yes, I know that Before your answer I did run that command and it revert the lock file, and then using "git revert " mentioned by you I also reverted the "empty link" commit.

Comment: While making pr I merge the last branch and commit first and then merge the first branch and commit. That is why in my first pr I get both commits and that yarn lock was in my last branch and commit. And that's why they ask me to revert that Because i also made pr of this after the first pr.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. If my answer was correct and helped you, please accept it. If not, just say so and I'm happy to delete it.